# How to do facebook login integration in magento website?

Tags: php, facebook, magento

I want to integrate facebook login in my magento website.would anyone give me steps to do that?

Thanks

Comment: your question is too abstract here, read the FAQ before posting your next question. Steps for this are obvious in such abstraction level: search on google , search for extensions that do this for you

Comment: Actually I want to login in my magento website through facebook.I installed one facebook integration tool.I also made an facebook app and got the AppId and Secret which i inserted in related section in magento admin.My issue is after inserting my facebook login details it always redirects me to a blank page which sticks there and not to my website page and after that nothing happens.

Comment: well thats good for you but how do others suppose to know that by reading your question? off to FAQ page you go

Comment: Try this. You can install it directly from admin panel.

http://store.velanapps.com/products/magento/free-facebook-login-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-login.html
this may be useful to you

Comment: you can use for latest magento so please see hear to change code: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/facebook-connect-and-like-free-compitible-1-8-1-0/

Comment: Here is the extension to let users login to your website by using Facebook, Twitter, Gmail or Yahoo account.
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/social-facebook-twitter-login-extension.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Inchoo facebook connect. it works like a charm and its free.

STEPS TO USE:

STEP1: goto http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/

Step2: Download the extension. (It is compatible with CE 1.6.2... have tested it and im using it. You can also check up other usage instructions on that page also)

Step3: Setup Application on Facebook and obtain its App ID/API Key and Application Secret.

Step4: Open downloaded module and copy its contents in app folder

Step5: Also copy the template and layout folders under app/design/frontend/default/default/ to app/design/frontend/yourinterface/yourtheme/ folder

Step6: Open Magento backend goto Configuration->Customer->Facebook Connect, fill in the ids etc, set Enabled to Yes

Step7: Refresh Cache / Reindex All

Step8: Add rel="facebook-connect" anywhere within a button tag or a tag. This can be put anywhere in CMS, static block or templates, and it should open up a popup for Facebook login.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Also try "Facebookall" http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/17223/s/facebook-all-5044/category/12860/

Comment: How to show the inchoo social login buttons in one page checkout page