# How to make a login with Facebook?

Tags: magento

What is the best/fastest way to create a login connect with facebook?

Are there some awesome free extension that can do that?

I know this is one of those open questions. Just looking for a hint or an extension. Then I will read my way to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Facebook Connect Magento Extension](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/facebook-connect-magento-extension/) (free) or [Facebook Login by Magestore](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-login.html) (pay)

See [How to do facebook login integration in magento website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136076/how-to-do-facebook-login-integration-in-magento-website)

Comment: I am looking for freeware/opensource.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Relevant content from the linked source should be included for posterity's sake; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/188727.